# Assets are being processed after server start in vue3/webpack5 app

Tags: vuejs3, quasar, webpack-5

I upgraded vue2 to vue 3 and webpack to webpack5. I am facing a stange issue. When i run dev server i can see assets are being processed after starting server.
Here is output :

[image]

I beleive this is the reason for not loading css and js files.
Can anyone help me here ?

Thanks!

Comment: This is hot-module reload - clearly marked with `[hmr]`. The reason for not loading CSS and JS is probably something else.

Comment: Thanks @IVOGELOV, any indea what could be the reason for not loading assets? I am new to this webpack thing.

Comment: New? If you are using Vue-CLI v5 it uses Webpack both for Vue2 and for Vue3. If you are not - the official recommendation is to use Vite (which uses Rollup instead of Webpack).

Comment: I am not using vue-cli right now, as i told you i upgraded both webpack and vue to latest version. Shall i used vue-cli ? is it required ?

Comment: It is not required but it makes things easier. When you check the Network panel in DevTools - what do you see? A bunch of 404 errors ? Did you check the `initiator` column to see where each of the assets is being requested from?

Comment: No, I cant see any error in network panel for any resources. Looks like these assets were not added to code at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254069/discussion-between-amit-kumar-and-ivo-gelov).